# Short story in White Dwarf magazine about a travelling wizard and a village being terrorised by some kind of demon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, demons, games-workshop

I'm trying to remember the title and author of a short story in White Dwarf magazine from the eighties.

All I can remember is a travelling wizard type arriving at a small village which is being terrorised by some kind of demon (spelt Daemon, maybe). Shape shifting is involved somehow. I remember it being very dark and atmospheric and the use of magic very well done, shamanistic, animalistic even. I think it may have been set in winter, or at least a cold and inhospitable landscape.

Comment: My husband has just searched all his old White Dwarfs from #1 - #76 (April 1986) and hasn't found it, so the latter half of the 80s if that helps anyone to search.

Comment: @Alison those magasines will be collectors editions now!

Comment: @Alison, thanks for looking! late eighties it is then :¬)